# his ancestral roots in counties Louth and Mayo

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

> Biden will spend three of the four days of his trip in the Republic, where **he will pay homage to his ancestral roots in counties Louth and Mayo**.

[Source](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2023/04/08/joe-biden-is-wrong-to-claim-credit-for-peace-in-ireland/?WT.mc_id=tmgoff_youtube_youtube-community)

---

Are his ancestral roots in counties Louth and Mayo or will he pay homeage while in counties Louth and Mayo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can certainly infer this fact:

1. Biden's roots are in County Mayo (on the west coast of Ireland) and County Louth (on the east coast).

It also seems likely that:

2. Biden will "pay homage" in County Mayo and County Louth during visits to those counties.

I put scare quotes around "pay homage" since what will actually happen is that he will visit the counties.  The use of "homage" is journalistic hyperbole.

The interpretation is pragmatic. It would be unlikely that Biden would "pay homage to his roots" in two random locations that are unrelated to the counties that his ancestors came from. It is possible that he won't actually visit one or both counties (but the journalist who knows his roots mentioned them both)

Note, Irish county names mostly are of the form "County X" whereas English and Scots county names are either single words (Sussex, Devon) or use the suffix "-shire"  (Yorkshire, Cheshire) Hence "counties Mayo and Louth" is a shorthand form of "County Mayo and County Louth"

Comment: Irish people very often drop the 'County', e.g. _I suspect you're a Kerry man_, _Here is the weather in Louth for today, courtesy of Met Éireann._

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with ***County Louth***, but it seems to be the same as ***County Mayo*** in that the first word is part of the name. Hence one might say *He's from County Louth* (note the capitalization).

But we *don't* say *He's from County Sussex*, because the word "County" isn't part of the name. And just as we don't say things like *My friends include Peters Smith and Jones*<sup>1</sup>, you can't have "County" apply to both counties at once.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case it's not obvious, *My friends include Peter Smith and Peter Jones*.

Comment: Does "in counties Louth and Mayo" modify "his ancestral roots" or does it modify "pay"?

Comment: _County_ customarily precedes the name in (I think) all counties in Ireland, both North and South. In England _County Durham_ is the only county which customarily uses the word "county" in its name. "XXX County" is as far as I know never used to refer to any counties in the British Isles.

Comment: Syntactically, that's ambiguous - but in this *specific* case it's hard to see how it could make any difference to the meaning anyway. He'd hardly be likely to pay homage to his Irish ancestors while he was on holiday in Greece, or pay homage to his Greek ancestors while he was in a couple of Irish counties, would he? But something like *He called his friend in London* could mean he was in London making the call, or the friend was in London *taking* the call.

Comment: @Colin: The now-ubiquitous chatgpt assures me that *Dublin
    Cork
    Clare
    Galway
    Kerry
    Kilkenny
    Limerick
    Tipperary
    Waterford
    Wicklow* don't normally have "County" as part of their name. It may not be bulletproof, but I'm pretty sure I never hear County Limerick, for example.

Comment: ChatGPT is, as usual, talking through its arse. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Counties_of_the_Republic_of_Ireland

Comment: @ColinFine - your 'all counties in Ireland' is true of the 'traditional' counties, but, as in the UK and elsewhere, local government reorganisation has been a thing. In 1994, County Dublin was split into a city (Dublin City) and three smaller counties:  Dún Laoghaire–Rathdown, Fingal, and South Dublin. The latter three do not have 'County' as part of their name.

Comment: You do see Americans writing (and hear them saying) that e.g. 'Brighton is in Sussex county'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sure. But I doubt you'd ever encounter "Brighton is in County Sussex" from a native!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I spent a night in the Royal County Sussex hospital in Brighton once.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: perhaps your confusion was due to fever or anaesthesia. It's the [Royal Sussex County Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Sussex_County_Hospital), originally the "Sussex County Hospital", which I parse as "Sussex [County Hospital]".

Comment: @ColinFine - accompanying my first wife's prolonged labour. Perhaps it was all the cigarettes (there were plenty of ashtrays in the waiting area in 1977). I meant to type 'Royal Sussex County', as you did.